# TextView to display only limited text and in single line

Tags: android, android-layout

I have made an android browser named Nidhi-The Browser which is in playstore, it is my personal self taught project. But I am having issue where I want to make my URL be as in chrome like in a line and limited text to show and not to go multiple line in the text field.

Comment: setSingleLine: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setSingleLine(boolean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Add this code into you TextView code in the XML file

```
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxLines="1"
```